# Runtime.getRuntime.exec("color 0a") not working?

Tags: java, runtime

I tried that to change the color of the DOS window by doing:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("color 0a");
```

But it doesn't work and shows me the current exception:

http://postimg.org/image/9o8xj54tf/

That line is in the main of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a method that works, which is the following:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "color 0a").inheritIO().start();
```

It starts a process of cmd.exe with the command

> color 0a

And then redirects the output to the console.

Answer (score 2):

The 'color' command is actually not an executable binary and therefore cannot be executed outside of `cmd.exe`.

If you want to open a MS-DOS window from Java, use this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /K color 0a");
```

or save your MS-DOS commands to a .bat file and run them in sequence using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /K your_batch_file.bat");
```

Comment: But can't I change the color of the window?